# Dispatch not hooked to windows memory

Tags: jacob

Sometimes I get an error (exception):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dispatch not hooked to windows memory
```

What does it mean? How to prevent it?

This is a sample code that results in this error:

```
import com.jacob.activeX.*;
import com.jacob.com.*;

public class Hooked {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ActiveXComponent e = new ActiveXComponent("Excel.Application");
    ActiveXComponent sh = new ActiveXComponent(
      e.getProperty("ActiveSheet").toDispatch());
    System.out.println(sh.getPropertyAsString("Name"));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means that `Dispatch` `= nothing` using vba syntax, it's empty. The same dispatch that you receive with `new Dispatch()`. Unfortunately Jacob 1.17 does not provide any method to explicitly check whether the `Dispatch` is empty or not. So I see 3 possible solutions:

1) **Use `Variant.isNull()`** after receiving the Variant from COM call, before converting it to Dispatch. So it requires 1 additional line:

```
  Variant vsh = e.getProperty("ActiveSheet");
  if (vsh.isNull()) {
    System.out.println("Null dispatch received.");
  }
  ActiveXComponent sh = new ActiveXComponent(vsh.toDispatch());
```

2) **Catch `IllegalStateException`** when using suspected Dispatch for the first time.

3) **Write a custom `isNull(Dispatch d)` function**

```
public static boolean isNull(Dispatch d)
{
  try {
    Dispatch.call(d, "");
  }
  catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
    return true;
  }
  catch (ComFailException cfe) {
    // that's ok, we didn't expect this call to succeed
  }
  return false;
}
```

In the specific example in the question the call was just a mistake, because Excel has no ActiveSheet if no workbook is open or created.